# Nvidia Settings does not start

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

When I try to start Nvidia Settings, nothing happens. I'm running ubuntu 18.04
Running `sudo nvidia-settings` gives

> No protocol specified
>   Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help`
       for usage information.

What does that error message mean? I know for sure I have Nvidia driver installed, because `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` outputs

> libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'VimCrypt~01!a9|׳�z�jq/�p����Sm'
>   libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with '᫐��e,a�`�9@�d'
>   libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf line 3: ignoring bad line starting with '���j&���Y´�o�x{8��T���&���g�ej'
>   libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf line 4: ignoring bad line starting with '�^�M!�������d�}�םfq�b�65�'
>   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
>       Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. UHD Graphics 620
>
> ### Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP108M [GeForce MX150]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia